# Office 365 "Update Banner" asking users to try Teams, try Power BI, etc

Tags: microsoft-excel

Within the last couple weeks, Office 365 has started to get a little intrusive.  First, in Word it popped up a "tip" telling users that they should save their documents to OneDrive or SharePoint so multiple people can work on it at once (we don't want them to do this).  Today Excel is popping up a "tip" telling users to use Power BI:

[image: Excel prompting for Power BI]

Is there a way to disable these prompts?

Comment: While I look into what this setting is called.  You are an Administrator on the network?

Comment: Yes I am and I haven't been able to find anything so far.